# Adding member field for 3rd library type

Tags: c++, c++11

I am dealing with a library that contain a type (let us say rectangle) as follow:

```
namespace some_lib{
    struct rectangle{
        int x;
        int y;
        int width;
        int height;
    };
}
```

I have a vector of this rectangles (very huge vector maybe 10^9 rectangle) and I want to compute the area of this rectangles and use it in many places of the program.

I want to compute it once of course. So I should store it somewhere. I can not edit the struct. I suggested this solution:

```
namespace my_own_program{
    struct rectangle_wrapper{
        some_lib::rectangle rect;
        int area;
        operator some_lib::rectangle() const { return rect; }
    };
}
```

Now I can store the area in this structure and if I want to pass the vector to the library to do some process on it, I have to casting it while copying it to another vector.

I feel this method is rubbish. I solved the problem of computing areas but also casting in each time I need to process it in the library seems horrible.

**My question:**

How can I achieve this in more better way?

Comment: Normally, I'd vote against distributing associated data over two different data structures, but as you apparently are forced to pass the vector back to the library, I would keep the area values in a separate `std::vector<int>`. Not nice either, but certainly less hassle than creating new copies all the time...

Comment: If you can't avoid the huge vector of rectangle, how about binding it with a vector of values holding the area. i.e.: `std::pair<std::vector<some_lib::rectangle>,std::vector<int>>` ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are stuck with using the library and you have to pass the vector many times, then I'd suggest creating a "shadow vector" that holds the area for each rectangle i at index i.
It depends on how the vector is used though. If you have a high churn rate, then this is obviously not the way to go, but then you shouldn't use a vector in the first place anyway.

You can wrap both vectors in a custom class that you use in your code to access the rectangles and also to pass the vector to the library.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer another solution:

```
struct rectangle{
        int x;
        int y;
        int width;
        int height;
};

struct extended_rectangle : public rectangle {
    int area;
};
```

In this case, you could pass the extended_rectangle to any function expecting a rectangle type (which probably is passed as reference)

UPDATE: after reading  Aconcagua's comment, to be more precise:

If you want to call a 3rd function which receives as parameter a vector --a contiguous memory block-- with the sequence of objects (that is, as a c-vector) you have no solution, as Aconcagua indicated (thank you, Aconcagua, I did not think about that detail).

But, if you have selected your rectangle_wrapper which is not possible to pass as a parameter of contiguous objects, I would prefer my extended_rectangle solution.

If you want the objects to be in a vector, you could use any solution based on a vector of pointers to objects in order to take advantage of polymorphism (you could process *v[i] as a rectangle).

Comment: Played around with this, too. Problem: You don't get it into an appropriate vector to be passed to the functions OP is talking of...